# How to write a decorator for a class based view -- permision based on object from view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

right now I'm using this app for permission checking: [django-rules](https://github.com/maraujop/django-rules)

However it hasn't been updated for over a year now and there's no decorator for the "new" (since django 1.3) class based views. I would like to be able to use at the urls.py like this:

```
url(r'^casos/(?P<pk>\d+)/editar/$', rules_permission_required('lawsuits.logical_check', raise_exception=True)(CaseUpdateView.as_view()), name='case_edit'),
```

I can't figure out how to get the object from the class based view from the decorator. Do you guys have any idea? Here's what I have so far:

```
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
def rules_permission_required(perm, queryset=None, login_url=None, raise_exception=False):
    def wrapper(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            #view_func is the class based view -> <function MyEditView at 0x94e54c4>

            print view_func.get_object() # doesnt work
            print view_func(request, *args, **kwargs).get_object() # doesnt work either

            #any ideas?

            if not request.user.has_perm(perm, obj=obj):
                return redirect_to_login(request, login_url, raise_exception)
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Use `method_decorator` on the dispatch() method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class ClassBasedView(View):
    @method_decorator(rules_permission_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ClassBasedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you could decorate the output of the `as_view` class method, either in your url config  (as described in the link above), or by saving the instance into a variable.

```
class ClassBasedView(View):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ClassBasedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
class_based_view = rules_permission_required(ClassBasedView.as_view())
```

Though I'm not quite sure whether the last example could cause thread safety problems (depends on how Django handles the instances). The best way is probably to stick with the `method_decorator`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a class decorator

```
def rules_permission_required(perm, queryset=None, login_url=None, raise_exception=False):

    def wrapper(cls):                
        def view_wrapper(view_func):
            @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
            def inner(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                # get object
                obj = get_object_from_classbased_instance(
                        self, queryset, request, *args, **kwargs
                    )

                # do anything you want
            return inner
        cls.dispatch = view_wrapper(cls.dispatch)
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Can someone explain why switching to class based views is an improvement when it overly complicates things like this.  Seems to be a step in the wrong direction if you ask me.